# How to migrate only a part (subset, folder) of one Git repository to another

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-subtree

I have a bitbucket repo A that I've been using for development. The production code is only a subset of the code on bitbucket repo.

I want to continue using repo A for development and migrate only the production code subset to repo B. Is this possible?

i.e.

### Source repository A

(Bitbucket)

```
    /src
      /a.py
      /b.py
```

### New repository B

(GitHub)

```
    /src
      /a.py
```

(repo B has no b.py).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detach subdirectory into separate Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what [git-submodules](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) are made for. If your production code can be separated to a single directory, you can use [git-subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository) to easily organize a submodule.

Then you'll be able to manage production code as a separate repo and have it on GitHub without all the other code.